# PHP - Wait specific time for execution of single line, otherwise return

Tags: php, wait, proc-open

As a matter of fact I have a `proc_open` function which will execute a command and pipe it's sub-commands to it. There is a problem here which will occur sometimes and not usually.

**Problem**

When I want to get process piped out output there is no response from destination server and script will wait for response up to .....

**Question**

I want to say that wait for response for 20 sec and if you didn't get any response. return from function. This is important that I don't want to stop script execution but just return from function.
Am I have to use multi thread libraries as POSIX?

Is there any way to implement this idea?
Any idea will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

**Code Sample**

```
<?PHP
set_time_limit(0);

.....

public function test()
{
    foreach ($this->commands as $cmd)
    {
        fwrite($pipes[0], "$cmd \n");   

        //Sometimes PHP stuck on the following line
        //Wait for almost 20 sec if respond did not came return
        $read = fread($pipes[1], 2096) . "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe this can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7749869/how-can-i-set-time-out-for-fread-when-access-socket

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say what OS this is running on, though you mention POSIX. Nor which SAPI. Collectively these have a lot of impact on your options.

Also, you've not said what the process you have started is, nor how it should be treated when it times out. Closing the stdio streams may force the process to crash. If you want to send a signal, you'll need to know the pid (IIRC not available from proc_open()).

The immediate problem you have is that the stream, by default is blocking reads, hence simply setting it to non-blocking gets you past the first hurdle:

```
set_stream_blocking($pipes[1],false);
...

fwrite($pipes[0], "$cmd \n");
$ttl=time()+20;
while(''==$read && time()<$ttl) {
   $read=fread($pipes[1],2096);
   if (!$read) sleep(1);
}
if (!$read) echo " timeout";
```

(BTW this probably won't work on mswindows)

Comment: I'm working on telegram-cli in Ubuntu. piping multiple command to the process and it will executing them one by one. but when I use your method everything messed up and order of executing and result changed!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Use **stream_set_timeout** (but after the fwrite if same stream):

```
fwrite($pipes[0], "$cmd \n");   
stream_set_timeout($pipes[1], 20);
$read = fread($pipes[1], 2096) . "\n";
```

**edit:**
In some special cases you must use stream_select() instead, do to bugs in PHP.

```
$r = [$pipes[0]];
$w = $e = null;
if( stream_select($r, $w, $e, 20) !== false )
  foreach($r as $s)
    $read = fread($s,2096);
```

I hope this helps?

Comment: Thanks for reply but there was no change in functioning

Comment: As before, program waits for response and response won't come but program wait and wait...